# Why do I not get a warning from my alertrule?

Tags: azure

In the portal (manage.windowsazure.com) I created a metric for a healthcheck of my vm:
`configure` -> `monitor` -> `endpoints` -> "http://mysite.cloudapp.net/my-healthcheck".
Then I created a new alert rule, where I chose this metric with `response time` and entered a threshold of 10 seconds:
[image] 
For testing, I stopped my frontend on this VM. As you can see in the picture below, the response time passed my threshold.
But everything is "green" - no alert is shown. What did I miss?

[image: alert rule]

Edit: 
additional information:
For testing I created an alertrule for CPU usage over 0.1% on the same machine: this works (I get an alert) - but it still doesn't work for my self-created metric (although the threshold is passed). And in the preview-portal I don't even see my metric when I try to create an alert rule. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just a little time after I started the bounty, I found a solution by myself:
I had to go to the new portal (preview portal) and create an **Application Insights**-ressource. There, I go to "Availability" and create a new "webtest". Here I can enter a specific URL for testing and the expected response code (e.g. 200). This works for me now!

[image]

So now I have to find out what the difference between the pricing tiers is (what does "days raw data retained", "data points included" and "aggregated data" mean in that case?)